# How I write this function so that each time i returns me new record of table on the screen

Tags: java

```
private void next_contactActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String name, lName, add, em, cell = null;
    try {
        String Url = "Jdbc:Odbc:DirDSN";
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Url,"sa","mysql");
        //Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM PersonInformation";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql,
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            name = rs.getString("First_Name");
            lName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            add = rs.getString ("Address");
            em = rs.getString("Email_Id");
            cell = rs.getString("cell#");
            jTextField2.setText(name);
            jTextField3.setText(lName);
            jTextField4.setText(add);
            jTextField5.setText(em);
            jTextField10.setText(cell);
        }
        con.close();
    } catch(Exception sqlEx) {
        System.out.println(sqlEx);
    } finally {
    }
}
```

I have written this next function for next button. I want when I click the next button the `rs.Next()` returns a new record of table on the screen. Now I am facing the problem that each time when I click the next button I get the first row of the table. I have also used `while (rs.Next())` but it returns me the last row of table each time I click the next button. Please tell me how I can write this function such that each time I call this function it returns a new record from the table.

Comment: Fix your tabbing and spacing before you post here please.

Comment: Please start sentences with capital letters. Functions "return" results, they don't "return you" results. Make us *want* to read your question!

Answer (score 2):

Change `ResultSet rs` to a member variable or save the position you're in and use it as a parameter for the method (see [LIMIT](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-limit.html)).

At the moment, you create a new ResultSet with every click, always starting at index 0.

Comment: @ s3b i am new in java , please if u provide me some code related to this. which tell me how i save the position i am in .

Comment: Just make a private ResultSet member which saves the position for you.

Comment: You know what a [member variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable) is, right? Change your local variable "rs" to a member variable. Create an extra method for your connection stuff. The only code that should be in your actionPerformed method should be the if(rs.next()) block. I won't code it for you, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @s3 i have done this by defining the extra method and i did call this method into constructor , now it works fine